# Gauss error function implementation for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a free (BSD- or MIT-licensed) [Gauss error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) implementation written in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Comment: I meant the error function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score 11):

I did some research on Gaussian approximation. 
My best found in accuracy/performance is :

var gaussrand = (Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()-3);

This trick may seem ugly but it give your a null average and sigma²=1/2 as expected.

I hope this will help.

Comment: This one answers a completely different question. For starters, the requested function takes an argument which it then maps to some value between -1 and 1, whereas this one produces one input-independent random value between -3 and 3.

Comment: Indeeed i made an approximation for normal gaussian function, not gaussian error function, i apologize 8 years later

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code, using the [approximation from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions) as described in Peter Mortensen's response
Original credit goes to [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun).

```
        function erf(x) {
            var z;
            const ERF_A = 0.147; 
            var the_sign_of_x;
            if(0==x) {
                the_sign_of_x = 0;
                return 0;
            } else if(x>0){
                the_sign_of_x = 1;
            } else {
                the_sign_of_x = -1;
            }

            var one_plus_axsqrd = 1 + ERF_A * x * x;
            var four_ovr_pi_etc = 4/Math.PI + ERF_A * x * x;
            var ratio = four_ovr_pi_etc / one_plus_axsqrd;
            ratio *= x * -x;
            var expofun = Math.exp(ratio);
            var radical = Math.sqrt(1-expofun);
            z = radical * the_sign_of_x;
            return z;
        }
```